# How can use jQuery or javascript in amp pages Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, jquery, third-party-module, amp

I have used amp module in Magento 2. I want to add custom jQuery to add a class on button click but jQuery is not working. Even I tried to run jQuery in console but this is not working in console also.

Comment: kindly share the steps you followed or ss.

Comment: I have added normal jQuery to add class on a click on a span tag inside phtml file like below code: 

 require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
           $('.costom-title').click(function(){
               $('.main-container .list'). addClass('custom-class');
           });        
        });